# double て verb. please help

Tags: て-form

I often have heard my japanese colleagues a double て used. example, kuruma nottete, ushiro mitete, genba ittete.

what i know is single te is command but what does double te mean? does it make more stress or what?

yoroshiku onegai itashimasu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second て form is the て form of the verb that is used after the first one which is いる in this case.

> 見てて → 見ていて

As for the meaning, there is a slight nuance but if you know the difference between the る and ている form, there should be no problem. It would be like saying in English:

> 後ろ見て : I looked back (and...)
>
> 後ろ見てて : I was looking back (and...)